# Использование цикла for

Tags: javascript

На странице есть таблица элементов, необходимо в определенное место добавлять кнопку, вот код скрипта:

```js
var input = document.getElementsByClassName('address')[0].innerText;
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('order')[0].getElementsByTagName('td')[4];
var a = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode('Геолокация');
a.appendChild(linkText);
a.target = "_blank";
a.className = "grey";
a.href = "https://yandex.ru/maps/?text=Город, " + input;
button.appendChild(a);
```

Код рабочий, но добавляет кнопку только на на первый элемент ('order')[0], а их много, штук [100], td[4] постоянный, прописывать для каждого ('order') свой код как то не по феншую, есть ли возможность организовать сей процесс через цикл for?
('address')[0] и ('order')[0] идут по порядку, то есть когда ('address')[1] то и ('order')[1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let addresses = document.getElementsByClassName('address');
let orders = document.getElementsByClassName('order');

Array.from(addresses).forEach((el, index) => {
    let address = addresses[index].innerText;
    let order =  orders[index].getElementsByTagName('td')[4];
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    let linkText = document.createTextNode('Геолокация');
    
    a.appendChild(linkText);
    a.target = "_blank";
    a.className = "grey";
    a.href = "https://yandex.ru/maps/?text=Город, " + address;
    order.appendChild(a);       
});
```

```html
<div class="address">text 1</div>
<div class="order">order 1 
<table><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>1</td></tr></table>
</div>

<div class="address">text 2</div>
<div class="order">order 2
<table><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>2</td></tr></table>
</div>

<div class="address">text 3</div>
<div class="order">order 3
<table><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>3</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

---

Но лучше опираться непосредственно на html, который у вас есть, и который вы не предоставили в впоросе

Comment: Есть прокол в этой схеме, если в поле address нет адреса, то адрес берется у соседнего элемента и в итоге все адреса сдвигаются)) Если адреса по факту нет, то class="address" не появляется на странице.

Comment: @Влад Читайте концовку ответа - это и есть самый большой прокол

Comment: Виноват, техзадание обозначил не полностью, но теперь то же все предельно ясно, если нет класса class="address" значит пропускать, сам пытаюсь исключение сделать, не выходит....

Comment: Могу вставить html, но есть ли смысл? Он один в один похож на ваш проверочный, с тем лишь исключением что в одном месте нет class="address", код на странице формируется динамически, может адрес быть, а может не быть.

Comment: @Влад считаю вот что: на текущий вопрос дан был ответ. Если есть нюансы - то либо их нужно было сразу описывать, либо теперь задавать новый вопрос)) А также я считаю, что класс `address` должен быть всегда у элемента, а не зависеть от того, есть ли текст или нет. Это более корректный вариант. Потому что не нужно обрабатывать исключительную ситуацию. И ещё много тысяч исключительных ситуаций, которые под которые надо подгонять код, а не сразу всё одним махом решить))

Comment: Увы, но ситуация такая, что я могу воздействовать на страницу только через JS, код я уже подогнал, за исключением ситуаций когда адреса нет, ну что ж попытаюсь задать вопрос еще раз.

Comment: Своих "хотелок" добился другим способом, просто добавил во все мне нужные пустые поля class="address", теперь все норм! Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: @Влад собственно, об этом я и писал выше сразу))